# find a limit of a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

I started doing this problem, but got stuck in the middle:

I want to find the distributional limit to $$\frac {xe^{\frac{-x^2}{s^2}}}{s^3}$$ when $s\rightarrow 0$ :

Here`s what I did: usig integration by parts

$\int_R \frac {xe^{\frac{-x^2}{s^2}}}{s^3} . \phi(x) dx=-\int_R \frac{e^{-x^2/s^2}}{s} . d(x\phi(x))= -\int_R \frac{e^{-x^2/s^2}}{s} . (\phi (x)+x\phi'(x)) dx$

how can I proceed now?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your distribution can be written as 
$$\frac {xe^{\frac{-x^2}{s^2}}}{s^3} = -\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac {1}{2s}e^{\frac{-x^2}{s^2}}\right).$$

Then you can say that by a well-known result (ask in comments if do not know how to prove it) $$\lim_{s\to 0} \frac {1}{2s}e^{\frac{-x^2}{s^2}} = \left(\frac 12 \int_\Bbb R e^{-x^2}dx\right)\delta_0.$$

Finally, another standard result in distribution theory is that if $T_n\to T$ in $D'$, then $T'_n\to T'$ in $D'$.

**edit**

Proof of the second equality (up to a factor $\frac 12$).

We simply write by definition for a test function $\phi$ and a change of variables $y = x/s$:
$$\left\langle\frac {1}{s}e^{\frac{-x^2}{s^2}},\phi(x) \right\rangle  = \int_\Bbb R \frac {1}{s}e^{\frac{-x^2}{s^2}}\phi(x)dx = \int_\Bbb R e^{ -y^2  }\phi(ys)dy.$$
By the dominated convergence theorem when $s\to 0+$ the latter integral converges to $$\int_\Bbb R e^{ -y^2  }\left(\lim_{s\to 0+}\phi(ys)\right)dy = \int_\Bbb R e^{ -y^2  }\phi(0)dy  = \left\langle \left(\int_\Bbb R e^{-y^2}dy\right)\delta_0,\phi\right\rangle$$

Comment: I think I did a mistake in integration by parts ! I`ll try to redo it again and see.

Comment: I understand what you said, but just to check. The limit you sated with delta comes from the fact that for any $f \in L^1$ then $lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} j^n  f(jx) = \delta $ ? just choose the function to be $e^{-x^2}$

Comment: I think I understand now.

Comment: can you please prove the result you talked about?

Comment: @Danny which one?

Comment: " Then you can say that by a well-known result (ask in comments if do not know how to prove it)" It makes me confused. I think I did it correctly by integration by parts, but I got different result than you have here!

Comment: @Danny see edits

Comment: Iam confused why do you get $ \delta$ and I get $\delta `$

Comment: He gets $\lim_{s\to 0} \frac {1}{2s}e^{\frac{-x^2}{s^2}} = \left(\frac 12 \int_\Bbb R e^{-x^2}dx\right)\delta_0$ but then you also have $\frac {xe^{\frac{-x^2}{s^2}}}{s^3} = -\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac {1}{2s}e^{\frac{-x^2}{s^2}}\right)$ so at the end you get $\delta'$ times a constant.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.